# Remove item from itemControls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I'm a beginner in wpf and I'like to know the best practices for handling crud operation on a list a user control.

As the  example below, I have create a list of individual and each of them are binding in a user control (mvvm...).

After several search, I have find possibility to uses a 'specific' binding with RelativeSource,FindAncestors etc...

But it seems to me very ugly because, it breaks the principle of inversion of dependency. How to be agnostic of the parent or how to bind from the parent an event/command for delete an item from a list.

Here's the main list

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <components:Individual Content="{Binding }" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

And here's the definition of the UserControl

```
<UserControl:Indivudual>
...
<TextBox Name="Text" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0"/>
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">Delete</Button>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: What's the goal of the UserControl? The simplest way would be to expose an IEnumerable and ItemTemplate properties, but that's just a ListControl. Encapsulating CRUD for a list of a type seems to specific for a UC, unless you're going to reuse it in multiple places.  Anyhow, expose ICommand properties on the surface for your UC and call them, passing in the items to be CUDed.  Expose one for the list (the R in CRUD).

Comment: The question is too broad to be answered well. In general, your `UserControl` should not need to know about the container, or the container of the data items it represents (i.e. the list). You should be able to have the `UserControl` connect `RoutedCommand` instances to the buttons, then have the `ItemsControl` or its container declare appropriate `CommandBinding` instances to handle the command. Absent a [mcve] showing clearly what your exact scenario is, it's not possible to know what you might actually need help with, beyond the already ample examples of such implementations on the web.

Comment: Well, I  try to split my code to minimal component but here, it's maybe overengineered. I'll forget the usercontrol the the individual item and do something like in this tutorial http://timdams.com/2011/02/08/adding-buttons-to-databound-listbox-items-in-wpf/